# Multiple discount in sql query 1 discount table

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a data table that looks like this:

```
---reservation_discount-----
id relation_id     title           rate
1  2               25% Discount    25
2  2               5% Discount     5
```

```
---reservation_hotel-----
id    room_id     price
2     1           2430
```

My query:

```
SELECT
reservation.customer,
hotel.title,
reservation_hotel.price,
reservation_discount.rate,
reservation_hotel.price * (100 - sum(reservation_discount.rate)) / 100 as total 
FROM
reservation_hotel
INNER JOIN reservation ON reservation_hotel.reservation_id = reservation.id
INNER JOIN hotel ON reservation_hotel.hotel_id = hotel.id
INNER JOIN room ON reservation_hotel.room_id = room.id AND room.hotel_id = hotel.id
INNER JOIN reservation_discount ON reservation_discount.relation_id = reservation_hotel.id
WHERE reservation_hotel.id=1
```

My question is:
I want him to take the discounts in order, but he doesn't get `25%` and `5%`, he gets `30%`.

How do I apply the discounts in order?

`Price: 2430 - 25% = 1822,5` and `1822,5 - 5% = 1731.375`

Comment: Why you don't have a third option for 28.75 % with  0.7125 as value (and of cour 0.75 and 0,95 for the other two. that would make the query much easier.

Comment: @nbk, What if the data is 40 and 30 for other ID and 10 and 2 for other IDs? The subtraction has to be generic enough.

Comment: you're right, but I need a SQL loop.

Comment: For loops you need functions or stored procedures. i see a possibility to do it like a rank foop. Order them correctly and the let a session variable do the trick, but for that i would need a full dbfiddle example to test it, with multiple reservations.

Comment: @nbk, [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8X4M88PDUcqzJcSvrrKWJ2/0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a more complex algorithm, this can have as many discount as you like to give and you can also select individual discount everytime.

In this example i took both reservation_hotel.id , but you can only use 1 or even all, as you wish. In this select query the reservation_hotel.id is called rh.id

This select statement

```
SELECT
  MIN(customer) customer,
  MIN(title) titke,
  MIN(price) price ,
  MIN(totalrate * 100) rate,
  MIN(total) total
FROM
  (SELECT
    rh.id id,
    r.customer customer,
    h.title title,
    rh.price price,
    rd.rate rate,
    if (@res = rh.id,@total :=@total,@total :=0) disc,
    if (@res = rh.id,@rate :=@rate,@rate :=0) disc2,
    if (@rate = 0, @rate := (100 - rd.rate)/ 100,@rate := @rate * (100 - rd.rate)/ 100) totalrate,
    if (@total=0,@total := rh.price * (100 - rd.rate) / 100,@total := @total * (100 - rd.rate) / 100) total,
    @res := rh.id        
  FROM
    reservation_hotel rh
    INNER JOIN reservation r ON rh.reservation_id = r.id
    INNER JOIN hotel h ON rh.hotel_id = h.id
    INNER JOIN room ro ON rh.room_id = ro.id AND ro.hotel_id = h.id
    INNER JOIN reservation_discount rd ON rd.relation_id = rh.id
    ,(SELECT @res := 0) r1,(SELECT @total := 0) r2,(SELECT @rate := 0) r3
  WHERE rh.id=1 or rh.id=2
  ORDER BY rh.id ) t1
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY id;
```

Gives you following result:

> ```
> customer | titke         | price |  rate |    total
> :------- | :------------ | ----: | ----: | -------:
> John Doe | Premium Hotel |  2430 | 71.25 | 1731.375
> John Doe | Premium Hotel |  2250 | 71.25 | 1603.125
> ```

DBfiddle example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=276a5474b1329d018ffacdc910ea5f10

It calculates the correct actual rate of the customer and the total amount.

Comment: thanks, It looks perfect, but we can narrow it down to one line. I want the grand total.

Comment: that doesn't matter, it can deal with any number of ids.

Comment: `1731.375 + 1603.125` how do I get the sums ?

Comment: See the new fiddle last query https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=150ec45705ac7e7a890a383515f6adca

Answer (score 1):

To solve this in a genereric manner, you need some kind of recursion. If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use a recursive common table expression.

The idea is to initially join the `reservation_hotel` with the record in `reservation_discount` that has the smallest `id` (using a correlated subquery), and to apply that first discount. Then, we get to the next discount, and apply it to the previously calculated price.

This query gives you the step by step calculation:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select r.*, r.price * (100 - d.rate) / 100 final_price, d.id discount_id
    from reservation_hotel r
    inner join reservation_discount d on d.id = (
        select min(d1.id) from reservation_discount d1 where d1.relation_id = r.id
    )
    union all
    select c.id, c.room_id, c.price, c.final_price * (100 - d.rate) / 100, d.id
    from cte c
    inner join reservation_discount d on d.id = (
        select min(d1.id) 
        from reservation_discount d1 
        where d1.relation_id = c.id and d1.id > c.discount_id
    )
)
select * from cte order by discount_id
```

```
id | room_id | price | final_price | discount_id
-: | ------: | ----: | ----------: | ----------:
 2 |       1 |  2430 |   1822.5000 |           1
 2 |       1 |  2430 |   1731.3750 |           2
```

If you just want the final price, then you can use aggregation:

```
with recursive cte as (
    select r.*, r.price * (100 - d.rate) / 100 final_price, d.id discount_id
    from reservation_hotel r
    inner join reservation_discount d on d.id = (
        select min(d1.id) 
        from reservation_discount d1 
        where d1.relation_id = r.id
    )
    union all
    select c.id, c.room_id, c.price, c.final_price * (100 - d.rate) / 100, d.id
    from cte c
    inner join reservation_discount d on d.id = (
        select min(d1.id) 
        from reservation_discount d1 
        where d1.relation_id = c.id and d1.id > c.discount_id
    )
)
select id, room_id, price, min(final_price) final_price
from cte
group by id, room_id, price
```

```
id | room_id | price | final_price
-: | ------: | ----: | ----------:
 2 |       1 |  2430 |   1731.3750
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=34bc4cea6c291a3790f90aacc42b5685)**